# Setting up HTTPS for a Google Cloud instance?

Tags: http, ssl, https, google-cloud-platform, lamp

I recently purchased a domain with Google Domains and linked it with Google Cloud - specifically Compute Engine. My website is up and running but I noticed that the connection is not secure, and I'm not sure why. Another domain that I set up with Google Firebase was automatically made secure (https by default, right when I set it up), but the new domain that I purchased is not. I have tried to search around on ways to make the domain secure but I have had no luck.

Comment: You need to purchase a SSL certificate for your domain from a SSL certificate vendor like GoDaddy or RapidSSL

Comment: I used LetsEncrypt to get one for free